# SQL condition join and calculation in select

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm

What I need to do is convert the decimal number to the selected currency. But only if there is a currency selected. But I still need to do another calculation.

What I have so far is this:

```
DECLARE @Currencies TABLE
(
    exchangerate decimal(10,4),
    currency uniqueidentifier,
    symbol varchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO @Currencies
SELECT exchangerate, @Currency, currencysymbol
FROM TransactionCurrencyBase
WHERE @Currency is not null AND TransactionCurrencyId = @Currency

INSERT INTO @Currencies
SELECT 1, null, '-'
WHERE @Currency is null

DECLARE @exchangerate decimal(10,4)
SET @exchangerate = (SELECT top 1 exchangerate
FROM            @Currencies)

DECLARE @Symbol varchar(5)
SET @Symbol = (SELECT top 1 symbol
FROM            @Currencies)

DECLARE @ProjBudget TABLE
(
                            projectname varchar(250),
    project uniqueidentifier,
    calcCurrency money,
                            symbol varchar(5),
                            currencyExchange decimal(10,4),
                            exchange decimal(10,4)
)

INSERT INTO @ProjBudget
SELECT o.Name, pa.new_projectactivityid, CASE WHEN pa.new_activitypercentage IS NOT NULL THEN  ((o.new_budgetmin/t.ExchangeRate)*@exchangerate) * 
(pa.new_activitypercentage / 100.0) ELSE  ((o.new_budgetmin/t.ExchangeRate)*@exchangerate) END AS Calc, currencysymbol, t.ExchangeRate, @exchangerate
FROM OpportunityBase o join TransactionCurrencyBase t on @exchangerate != 1 AND o.TransactionCurrencyId = t.TransactionCurrencyId
JOIN new_projectactivityBase AS pa ON o.OpportunityId = pa.new_Project
```

But this only works if a currency has been selected. 
Any ideas?

Comment: How is MySQL involved here?

Comment: ssrs and reporting services should not be tag too.. this should be just sql. its misleading.

Comment: MySQL was in the proposed tags. This is a query for a ssrs report, that is why  added it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this. Not sure if this is the but it works.

```
DECLARE @ProjBudget TABLE
(
    project uniqueidentifier,
    calcCurrency money,
    calcNoCurrency money
)

INSERT INTO @ProjBudget
SELECT pa.new_projectactivityid, CASE WHEN pa.new_activitypercentage IS NOT NULL THEN  ((o.new_budgetmin/t.ExchangeRate)*@exchangerate) * 
(pa.new_activitypercentage / 100.0) ELSE  ((o.new_budgetmin/t.ExchangeRate)*@exchangerate) END AS Calc,
CASE WHEN pa.new_activitypercentage IS NOT NULL THEN  o.new_budgetmin * 
(pa.new_activitypercentage / 100.0) ELSE  o.new_budgetmin END AS CalcWithoutExchange
FROM FilteredOpportunity o join FilteredTransactionCurrency t on o.TransactionCurrencyId = t.TransactionCurrencyId
JOIN Filterednew_projectactivity AS pa ON o.OpportunityId = pa.new_Project
```